# Importing aligned environment in TeX to Mathematica

Tags: latex, input, input-forms

The ToExpression command works well with scalars `\frac{x}{\sqrt{5}} \mu S_1`

```
ToExpression["\\frac{x}{\\sqrt{5}} \\mu S_1", TeXForm]
```

but fails when trying to use the `aligned` environment:

```
ToExpression["\\begin{aligned}
    \\frac{dS}{dt} & = - \\frac{S}{N} \\left( \\beta_1 i_1 + \\beta_2 \
i_2 \\right) +
    \\sigma_1 R_1 + \\sigma_2 R_2, & & \\\\
    \\frac{di_1}{dt} & = \\frac{\\beta_1}{N} S i_1 - \\gamma_1 i_1, & \
\\frac{di_2}{dt} & = \\frac{\\beta_2}{N} S i_2 - \\gamma_2 i_2
    \\end{aligned}", TeXForm]
```

giving a lot of `ErrorBox`es.

Is there a way to import this $\TeX$ expression to Mathematica?
The problem disappears when replacing the 'aligned' environment manually by a list:

```
ToExpression["\\{\\frac{dS}{dt}  =\\frac{\\beta_1}{N} (N-i_1-R_1-i_2- \
\\epsilon R_2) i_1- \\gamma_1 i_1,\\frac{dS}{dt}  \
=\\frac{\\beta_1}{N} (N-i_1-R_1-i_2- \\epsilon R_2) i_1- \\gamma_1 \
i_1\\}", TeXForm]
```

which compiles correctly. So, it seems this part of the conversion, i.e. removing the 'aligned' ,  should be done manually, which makes sense, for how could Mathematica have guessed what to do with the 'aligned'?

Comment: Hm, if you look at `TeXForm[{{a + b, c}, {d, e}}]`, you see that it gives `array`. However, when parsing back, `ToExpression[ToString@TeXForm[{{a + b, b, c}, {d, e, f}}], TeXForm]`, it gives a weird looking matrix ...

Answer (score 1):

Its complicated, but Import the LaTeX string and export it to a notebook is working.

```
    Export[path=Environment["userprofile"] <> "\\Desktop\\my.nb", 
     ImportString["\\begin{aligned}
      \frac{dS}{dt} & = - \frac{S}{N} \left( \beta_1 I_1 + \beta_2 I_2 \right) +
       \sigma_1 R_1 + \sigma_2 R_2, & & \\
       \frac{dI_1}{dt} & = \frac{\beta_1}{N} S I_1 - \gamma_1 I_1, & 
     \frac{dI_2}{dt} & = \frac{\beta_2}{N} S I_2 - \gamma_2 I_2, \\
     \frac{dR_1}{dt} & = \gamma_1 I_1 - \sigma_1 R_1, & 
      \frac{dR_2}{dt} & = \gamma_2 I_2 - \sigma_2 R_2.
\end{aligned}, "LaTex" ] ]


    Run[path ]
```

Probably there exists a way to proceed with the cell expression directly without creating a notebook.